# Android: where are the settings for default applications stored?

Tags: android

I am running Android 4.4.2 on my rooted Samsung Galaxy Note 3, and have an issue which is driving me nuts: the default dialler / phone app is never saved.

So my question is: where are the default applications setting saved? Maybe in some XML or SQLITE? I'm asking because I'd like to try writing the setting manually myself.
Or, alternatively, do you have any ideas on how I could fix this?

As an example of the problem, if I open WhatsApp, click on a contact's name, scroll to the bottom where it shows the phone number, and click on the phone number, I get a prompt: "complete action using" and the choice of a number of apps. If I choose an app and click on 'always', the choice is not saved: if I repeat these steps, I get the same annoying prompt.

If I go to Android settings --> general --> default applications I only see two categories: "Home" (i.e. the launcher) and Message (i.e. SMSs).

I have also tried instaling Default App Manager Lite (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager) but it doesn't work, it doesn't let me set these defaults.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> General -> Application manager -> find the app you want -> hit the 'Clear defaults' button which clears that app as being the default app to launch for some actions.

Comment: I suppose I wasn't clear. There is NO default app for the phone/dialler so I cannot clear a default which doesn't exist. I had tried clearing data for both the stock phone app and Viber, but to no avail.

Comment: This seems like something is broke in Android. Android Intent prompts aren't managed by developers on the level of saving them so pretty much it would seem either Samsung broke something or who knows what else.

Comment: I've also reproduced your issue on my Samsung Note 3. On my Nexus 5 the prompt is saved correctly. Looks like Samsung broke/changed something then.

Comment: How about the other part of my question? I.e. when I choose a phone app and click on 'always', where exactly is that setting supposed to be stored? Can I try to manually write the setting myself (my phone is rooted)?